# Check whether an OpenLayers map is being currently zoomed?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I know you can check whether a map is being *dragged* by examping its *dragging* property like

```
olMap.dragging
```

This is a boolean value that is true if the map is being dragged (with the mouse or even with keyboard arrows).

But what about zooming in and out?

Comment: This is an openlayers 3 question, no?

Comment: maybe **zoomstart** and **zoomend** events of map help you. see the [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html).

Comment: Thanks @HasanRamezani. I did end up attaching callback functions to the zoomstart and zoomend events in order to determine when the map was being zoomed, but I found it odd that for dragging, there exists a boolean value that we can inspect directly, while zooming requires attaching callback functions.